# Image not showing on other browsers

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a simple website with html and css and i realised that my logo is not showing on other browsers or other users.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq3At.png%5B1%5D)

here is html code:

```
 <section id="header">
    <div class="header container">
      <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="brand">
          <a href="#hero">
              <img src="/original-logo.jpg" width="180px" height="80px" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is it actually being successfully fetched per the Network Pane in the dev tools?

Comment: Your image has no error. Perhaps the image source link is incorrect.

Comment: @SatoTakeru yep fixed it, the path is wrong should not use / before the name

Comment: how can i close this question ?

Comment: You can delete this question, but I think the comments are useful and don't need to close.

Comment: Between the comments and the question on the left side you should see a few link options: "Share, Edit, Close, Delete, Flag".  You can "Delete" if you choose, or [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to leave the post and provide direction to others who may face a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the image path is defined wrong, that's why the image is not getting access to make it visible.

For Example:

If the image location in the same folder, you should add image with a `dot`. for example: `src="./original-logo.jpg")`

`<img src="./original-logo.jpg" width="180px" height="80px" alt="">`

The number of `dot's` will vary from folder to folder to get accessed.

Thanks